# XSLT, change some tags with prefix from lt/gt to <> and some still with lt/gt

Tags: xml, xslt

Maybe some help me decide a task :)
I have input xml for example:

```
<n0:sendRequests xmlns:n0="http://upg.sbns.bssys.com/" xmlns:prx="urn:sap.com:proxy:DAX:/1SAI/TAS530E8C549ADDED8C7693:740">
    <n0:requests>&lt;upg:Request xmlns:upg="http://bssys.com/upg/request" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" requestId="55555555-5555-5555-5555-550000090095" version="1" sender="1" receiver="1"&gt;&lt;upg:Models&gt;&lt;upg:Model&gt;&lt;StatementRequest xmlns="http://bssys.com/sbns/integration"&gt;&lt;docId&gt;90095&lt;/docId&gt;&lt;docDate&gt;2020-09-10&lt;/docDate&gt;&lt;docNumber&gt;90095&lt;/docNumber&gt;&lt;orgId&gt;6c74b51b-fb90-4270-8a1b-ae07177a8905&lt;/orgId&gt;&lt;orgInn&gt;7736050003&lt;/orgInn&gt;&lt;orgName&gt;JSC Company&lt;/orgName&gt;&lt;fromDate&gt;2020-05-11&lt;/fromDate&gt;&lt;toDate&gt;2020-05-11&lt;/toDate&gt;&lt;accounts&gt; &lt;Acc&gt;&lt;account&gt;40702810500010000848&lt;/account&gt;&lt;bankBIC&gt;044525220&lt;/bankBIC&gt;&lt;bankName&gt;ABR&lt;/bankName&gt;&lt;orgName&gt;JSC Company&lt;/orgName&gt;&lt;/Acc&gt;&lt;/accounts&gt;&lt;signCollection&gt;&lt;SignCollection&gt;&lt;/SignCollection&gt;&lt;/signCollection&gt;&lt;/StatementRequest&gt;&lt;/upg:Model&gt;&lt;/upg:Models&gt;&lt;/upg:Request&gt;
    </n0:requests>
    <n0:sessionId>0174774e-e79f-19d8-bf28-5e423cf0d53c</n0:sessionId>
</n0:sendRequests>
```

And i have xslt mapping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:upg="http://upg.sbns.bssys.com/" xmlns:n0="http://upg.sbns.bssys.com/">
 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="n0:requests">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[ </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

output should be:

```
  <n0:sendRequests>
    <n0:requests><![CDATA[
    <upg:Request requestId="13131313-0000-1111-2211-001111111111" version="1" sender="1" 
                 receiver="1" xmlns:upg="http://bssys.com/upg/request" 
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <upg:Models>
       <upg:Model>&lt;StatementRequest 
              xmlns=&quot;http://bssys.com/sbns/integration&quot;&gt; 
        &lt;orgId&gt;b14a6b8c-54ba-45af-8420-fdac775f6fe5&lt;/orgId&gt; 
        &lt;accounts&gt; 
                    &lt;Acc&gt; 
                               &lt;account&gt;40702810200000005400&lt;/account&gt; 
                               &lt;bankBIC&gt;044030861&lt;/bankBIC&gt; 
                    &lt;/Acc&gt; 
        &lt;/accounts&gt; 
        &lt;docDate&gt;2020-09-08&lt;/docDate&gt; 
        &lt;docId&gt;13131312-1fe4-11ea-9220-000c29bc93aa&lt;/docId&gt; 
        &lt;docNumber&gt;133&lt;/docNumber&gt; 
        &lt;fromDate&gt;2020-09-01&lt;/fromDate&gt; 
        &lt;orgInn&gt;7810356897&lt;/orgInn&gt; 
        &lt;orgName&gt;ЗАО  &quot;JSC Company&quot;&lt;/orgName&gt; 
        &lt;toDate&gt;2020-09-02&lt;/toDate&gt; 
        &lt;signCollection&gt;
        &lt;SignCollection/&gt;
        &lt;/signCollection&gt;
        &lt;/StatementRequest&gt; 
</upg:Model>
 </upg:Models>
</upg:Request>
 ]]></n0:requests>
     <n0:sessionId>01746e15-004e-14f5-b4e6-f6c8b357e000</n0:sessionId>
  </n0:sendRequests>
```

inside tag n0:requests needed replace &lt/&gt to <> for tags with prefix upg: and keep &lt/&gt for other tags without prefix (example <StatementRequest).

Now my xslt replace all &lt/&gt to <> :(
This is really can do it on XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your question is. Your stylesheet doesn't really do anything. Escaped XML is semantically equivalent to XML contained in a CDATA section. You could have achieved the same result much more simply and elegantly by doing just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:n0="http://upg.sbns.bssys.com/" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="n0:requests"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your expected output shows a CDATA section with some of the XML contents being escaped - which doesn't make any sense.

In general, when you have a string representing XML - whether escaped or contained in CDATA - and you want to make changes to the XML content of the string, it is best to convert the string to XML first, then process it normally using XSLT. Otherwise you are limited to string manipulation, which is very tedious and error-prone.

Comment: Input message doesn't contain CDATA, i should added him. Inside CDATA i'm should replace &lt/$gt to <> for tags with prefix upg: but this text contains tags for example StatementRequest and for this tags i should stay &lt.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am saying. XML inside CDATA is the same thing as escaped XML.. You say you want to have escaped XML inside CDATA. That would be  XML that is escaped **twice** - which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're discussing the problem in terms of the lexical XML in your input and output, but that's the wrong perspective with XSLT: you need to think about XSLT receiving a node tree from the parser, and passing a node tree to the serializer.

Note that your example output containing

```
<upg:Model>&lt;StatementRequest 
              xmlns=&quot;http://bssys.com/sbns/integration&quot;&gt;
...
&lt;/StatementRequest&gt; 
</upg:Model>
```

represents exactly the same node tree as

```
<upg:Model><![CDATA[<StatementRequest 
              xmlns="http://bssys.com/sbns/integration">
...
</StatementRequest>]]>
</upg:Model>
```

These are just different serializations of the same result tree, so as far as XSLT is concerned they are identical.

With a modern XSLT processor (XSLT 3.0) you can construct such a result using a construct like:

```
<upg:Model>
  <xsl:variable name="temp">
    <StatementRequest 
                  xmlns="http://bssys.com/sbns/integration">
      ...
    </StatementRequest>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="serialize($temp)"/>  
</upg:Model>
```

But the serialize() function is not available in earlier XSLT versions.